# Is it possible to for a user to authenticate with Azure B2C without going to microsoft login

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I'm aware of the limitation of B2C that dictates that it doesn't support 
Daemons/Server Side Apps applications authenticating with non-interaction.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-limitations/

In my case,

I have a user on my application whom is available to enter their details but i want complete control of the Journey, i don't want to have to redirect to https://login.microsoftonline.com etc...  to acquire the token.

I know the B2C Azure portal allows you to provide a static HTML page as a template for the login page, but this isn't good enough for my scenario.

My guess is this isn't currently supported but eventually will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is not possible due to the nature of the service. Full control of the pipeline is possible when you use the service that provides such capabilities out of the box. Here, it is more like that user is "isolated" from some of the boilerplate functionality which is the benefit sometimes.

If you need to have a full control, i think that you will need to use something like Windows Identity Foundation and federated authentication which may be customized.

Comment: I was of the same thought. That the point of B2C is to provide not just the authentication credential storage, but also provide the Identity mechanism layer.

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The type of authentication you are asking for is the **resource owner password credentials**. Right now, it is in scoping and they said it will be released by summer 2017. **Note:** Supports only for local accounts, not any external providers like FB, Google etc..

For more details https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/13817784-add-support-for-resource-owner-password-credential

You can **upvote** and let the team work on it